# PIL как сравнить разные по размеру картинки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pil

Картинки идентичные. только по размерам длине ширине отличаются

Всем привет. Есть страница( макет) есть сверстанная страница сайта ( сделал с нее скриншот)
как сравнить два разных по размерам файла ? один больше другой меньше .... пробовал сравнить... как есть... но думаю надо их как то подогнать под один размер. Есть какая то фишка автоподгона размера для сравнения ?

```
image1 = Image.open('test1.png')
width, height = image1.size
print('test1', width, height)
# test1 1887 6794

image2 = Image.open('test2.jpg')
width, height = image2.size
print('test2', width, height)
# test2 3840 13530

a = ich.soft_light(image1=image1,  image2=image2).save('rezultat.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать изменение разрешение, встроенное в PIL. То есть, оно ужимает изображение под ваши требуемые размеры, и можно это дело автоматизировать:

```
'''Ваш код, написанный выше'''

resized_image2 = image2.resize(image1.size)

print('Test1', image1.size[0], image1.size[1])
print('Test2', resized_image2.size[0], resized_image2.size[1])
```

output:

```
Test1 1887 6794
Test2 1887 6794
```

Это вроде как то, что вам нужно, но, боюсь, для сравнения изображений, не подойдёт простое изменение изображений. Скорее всего вам придётся использовать какое-никакое машинное обучение для этого дела, но это уже углубление в другую тему

---

Всем добра